# Flink 1.7.0 Dashboard not show Task Statistics

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use Flink 1.7 dashboard and select a streaming job. This should show me some metrics, but it remains to load.

I deployed the same job in a Flink 1.5 cluster, and I can watch the metrics.
Flink is running in docker swarm, but if I run Flink 1.7 in docker-compose (not in the swarm), it works

[image: flink 1.7 dashboard]

I can do it work, deleting the hostname in docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  jobmanager17:
    image: flink:1.7.0-hadoop27-scala_2.11
    hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "9254:9249"
    command: jobmanager
....
```

I delete the host name:

```
version: "3"
services:
  jobmanager17:
    image: flink:1.7.0-hadoop27-scala_2.11
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "9254:9249"
    command: jobmanager
....
```

and now the metrics works, but without the hostname...

Is it possible to have both?

PD: I read something about 'detached mode'... but I don't use it

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are running your cluster on Kubernetes or docker swarm. With Flink 1.7 on Kubernetes you need to make sure the task managers are
registering to the job manager with their IP addresses and not the
hostnames. If you look at the jobmanagers log you'll find a lot of warnings that the Taskmanager can't be reached.

You can do that by passing defining the `taskmanager.host` parameter. An example depoyment might look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
....
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "<%= name %>"
        args: ["taskmanager", "-Dtaskmanager.host=$(K8S_POD_IP)"]
        env:
          - name: K8S_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
```

If you are not running on K8 it might be worth a try to pass this parameter manually (by providing an IP adress which is reachable from the jobmanager as the `taskmanager.host`)

Hope that helps.

---

Update: Flink 1.8 solves the problem. The property `taskmanager.network.bind-policy` is by default set to "ip" which does more or less the same what the above described workaround does (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#taskmanager)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use docker swarm, but using docker-compose , it works. Is a clue, thanks

Comment: Haha. Close enough. I will edit my answer so that other people with a similar problem can find it too.

Comment: The problem still happens in 1.8. I just brew installed flink on my macbook air, and got the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235219/no-metrics-in-flink-webui, fixed it by provided taskmamnager.host:localhost in flink-conf.yaml.). By the way,  I have docker daemon running in my mac.

Comment: I guess docker on a macbook might be a slightly different setup. But interesting to know that the ip adress does not work here. I would guess that the taskmanager just does not know which ip to pick (really just a wild guess)